# Sound on the iPhone: Finch: Ensuring that sound actually plays

Tags: iphone, audio, openal, finch

I am using Finch to play sound. Works great. One exception: I get an incoming call, answer the call, hang up. Go back to the app. Now sounds don't seem to play correctly anymore. What is the most resource-friendly way of ensuring they will? I guess the audio session is somehow closed...

Comment: Please don't play any sound when the volume is muted. This is kinda annoying.

Comment: I don't see what that has to do with the question. Care to enlighten me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider just using CocosDenshion sound library.  we have found it solves all problems.  not perfect but very reliable.  hope it helps!

**Note** there is also the **ObjectAL** library, which, is possibly simply better than CocosDenshion.

Comment: Does everything I need. And it was very easy to set up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup your own OpenAL audio interrupter.

An example of how to do this is found in Apple's SDK example called oalTouch.

See:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/oalTouch/Introduction/Intro.html